# React - what should be the propType of Material UI icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am going to pass MUI icon to component `Test` and I want to create Protype for the icon, but I am not sure what should be the correct proptype of the icon

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import VisibilityIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";

import Test from "./Test";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test icon={<VisibilityIcon />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Test.jsx

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function Test(props) {
  const { icon } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      Icon:
      {icon}
    </div>
  );
}

Test.propTypes = {
  // icon: ??????
};

export default Test;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-curie-8mtbw?file=/src/Test.jsx:0-213

Comment: Does [this](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with `PropTypes.element` here if you want to be specific.

[Typechecking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

```
Test.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.element,
};
```

> ```
> // A React element.
> optionalElement: PropTypes.element,
> ```

If you want to be a little more loose/general, then use `PropTypes.node` for anything that is renderable.

> ```
> // Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array
> // (or fragment) containing these types.
> optionalNode: PropTypes.node,
> ```

[image: Edit react-what-should-be-the-proptype-of-material-ui-icon]

Answer (score 2):

**It should be a `PropTypes.element`**

```
Test.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.element
};
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit fervent-poitras-ubr96]